# What is the -> (forward arrow) operator in Wordpress/PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have downloaded a WordPress theme and in many places in the code I see the operator ->. It could be for example to retrieve a post ID like this:

```
$postID = $post->ID
```

I can't find what the arrow actually does in the background. Does it make a database call? Or is it simply fetching the ID from the $post variable, similar to `$postID = $post['ID']`?

Comment: The arrow operator is for accesing object properties or member functions.

Comment: @HonkderHase, thanks! So in this particular case it would be as efficient to use $post->ID in many places in a function instead of declaring the variable $postID = $post->ID and then use $postID instead?

Comment: with properties there is no difference, except that writing `$propVal` is much shorter than `$someObject->veryLongPropertyName` many times. With methods it's probably better to assign the result of a call to a variable instead of calling the method over and over again... depends on what the method does, but if the method perfoms "heavy" duties, don't run it more often than neccessary...

Comment: @HonkderHase, good explanation, cheers! Put it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow operator `->` is for accessing properties or method of an object.

Overhead of accessing properties is neglectible, but it's sometimes more comfortable to assign a property to a temporary variable, just because it shortens the source code. Example

```
$oPropValue = $objWithSpeakingName->propertyWithLongName;
```

However, it's often a good practice to save the return value of an method call to a temporary variable to avoid to much overhead. For example if the method performs a database query (and has no build-in caching), it would cause massive overhead to call the method over and over instead of calling it once an then reuse the value, f.e. in a loop.

```
$propValue = $objWithSpeakingName->doSomeWork();
while( ..condition.. ) {
    // work with $propValue
}
```

But it also depends on how a method is used and what it's doing. If it takes arguments, you might need to call it repeatedly with changing parameters, in order to get the job done.

```
while(..condition..) {
    $arg = .. // might change in the loop
    $propValue = $objWithSpeakingName->doMoreWork( $arg );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in PHP -> simply means it is accessing object properties, like how '.' works in other Object Oriented Languages like java.